# Same main.tex but compile pdfs with dynamic name & use variable in other file

Tags: output

i use Texmaker.

Is possible, when main.tex create many different pdf output.

i want to definite variable for output pdf name in "pdfoutputname.tex"

and then use this variable to main.tex

My minimal code in main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\input{pdfoutputname.tex}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\FileoutputVariableNull}{\FileoutputVariable[0]}

\begin{document}
Hello \\
File name pdf is \FileoutputVariableNull
\end{document}
```

IN "pdfoutputname.tex"

```
\def\FileoutputVariable{{"AAA","BBB"}}
```

wanted result: main.tex create AAA.pdf, not main.pdf
If someone has other idea, please share.
Thank in advance

Comment: Sounds like a standard shell script task. You may write something like `foreach $FileName in NameList.txt: prepend "\def\filename{$FileName}" to main.tex and compile main.tex`....... Notice that you are allowed to use `\def` even before `\documentclass`.

Comment: Another option is to pass `--jobname=AAA`  or `-jobname=AAA` to the `pdflatex`, `lualatex`, `xelatex`, etc. command you are using. This changes the name of the output file. You can access the given value by expanding the `\jobname` primitive in main.tex, however you can't modify it, as far as I know.

Comment: @Symbol1 Your solution is good, but i have tried and don't effort. Can you give more details? Thanks

Comment: My tests suggested it certainly may be easier to reverse your logic as suggested by  Symbol1 so "subfile" iterates through its fixed list of names calling main The alternative of trying to force jobname in main.tex caused me some issues trying to match your use of variables although it is a valid solution I found it flaky, either way it is not 100% clear enough from your question as to "expectation" for example I can change main.pdf to AAA.pdf but that using my attempts requires two passes 1st to get  the new name and second run to apply as renamed.output thus wasteful on resources